# Finding the TICKR number from a BeautifulSoup webscrape on Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Wikipedia to find the tickr(Symbol) numbers of the S&P 100 from this link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_100.

I think up until `row_soup_list = table_soup.find('tr')` that my code works, but `.find` seems to select too small a section of my `table_soup` but `.find_all` returns this error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

How can I scrape all the symbols?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url  = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_100'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

tag = 'table'
attributes = {'class':'wikitable sortable'}
table_soup =soup.find(tag, attributes)
print(table_soup)

symbol= []

row_soup_list = table_soup.find('tr')

print(row_soup_list)
for row_soup in row_soup_list:
    td_soup_list = row_soup.find('td')
    item = {}
    item['Symbol'] = td_soup_list[0].text
    symbol.append(item)
    
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues in your code:

- `.find()` gives the first matching result. `.find_all()` **returns a list** of all the matching results. Since you need all the rows, you must use `.find_all()`

  ```
  row_soup_list = table_soup.find_all('tr')
  ```
- You are adding those symbols to `items` dictionary. But your code only saves the last symbol to `items` since you are creating the dictionary everytime inside the loop. That must be initialized before the loop.

  ```
  item = {'Symbol': []}
  ```
- Also since `table` has a `<th>` tag which denotes the table heading, you need to skip it from `row_soup_list`. So use `row_soup_list[1:]` and iterate over it.

  ```
  for row_soup in row_soup_list[1:]:
  ```

Here is the correct code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url  = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_100'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

tag = 'table'
attributes = {'class':'wikitable sortable'}
table_soup =soup.find(tag, attributes)
symbol= []

row_soup_list = table_soup.find_all('tr')
item = {'Symbol': []}

for row_soup in row_soup_list[1:]:
    td_soup_list = row_soup.find('td')
    item['Symbol'].append(td_soup_list.text.strip())
    
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the symbols, you can select all the first  HTML `<td>` under the ID `constituents` with using a CSS selector `#constituents td:nth-of-type(1)`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_100"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

symbols = {
    "Symbols": [
        tag.get_text(strip=True)
        for tag in soup.select("#constituents td:nth-of-type(1)")
    ]
}

print(symbols)
```

Output:

```
{'Symbols': ['AAPL', 'ABBV', 'ABT', 'ACN', 'ADBE', 'AIG', 'AMGN', 'AMT', 'AMZN', 'AVGO', 'AXP', 'BA', 'BAC', 'BIIB', 'BK', 'BKNG', 'BLK', 'BMY', 'BRK.B', 'C', 'CAT', 'CHTR', 'CL', 'CMCSA', 'COF', 'COP', 'COST', 'CRM', 'CSCO', 'CVS', 'CVX', 'DD', 'DHR', 'DIS', 'DOW', 'DUK', 'EMR', 'EXC', 'F', 'FB', 'FDX', 'GD', 'GE', 'GILD', 'GM', 'GOOG', 'GOOGL', 'GS', 'HD', 'HON', 'IBM', 'INTC', 'JNJ', 'JPM', 'KHC', 'KO', 'LIN', 'LLY', 'LMT', 'LOW', 'MA', 'MCD', 'MDLZ', 'MDT', 'MET', 'MMM', 'MO', 'MRK', 'MS', 'MSFT', 'NEE', 'NFLX', 'NKE', 'NVDA', 'ORCL', 'PEP', 'PFE', 'PG', 'PM', 'PYPL', 'QCOM', 'RTX', 'SBUX', 'SO', 'SPG', 'T', 'TGT', 'TMO', 'TMUS', 'TSLA', 'TXN', 'UNH', 'UNP', 'UPS', 'USB', 'V', 'VZ', 'WBA', 'WFC', 'WMT', 'XOM']}
```